# how to make the paginator style clickable?

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I've added a class to style the Paginator to make it look like a button, but the only clickable area is the text inside , is there any way to fix that ?

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('next >>', array('class'=>'Paginator')); ?>
```

Comment: I assume changing your styles would do the trick, but we'd need to see them to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the cake.generic.css by default this is the form to make this.

```
   <?php 
            echo "<div class='paging'>"; 
            echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('anterior ', true), array(), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));
            echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(   'class' => 'numbers'     ));
            echo $this->Paginator->next(__(' siguiente', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
            echo "</div>"; 
    ?>
```